# How to map two components of the same type with Fluent NHibernate AutoMap Conventions

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

We are using Fluent NH with convention based mapping.  I have the following:

```
public class Foo() : Entity
{
  public BarComponent PrimaryBar { get; set; }
  public BarComponent SecondaryBar { get; set; }
}

public class BarComponent
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have it to the point where it will create the foo table with a single name field.  I've tried the following Override and it doesn't work.

```
  public class FooOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Foo>
    {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<Foo> mapping)
        {
            mapping.Component(x => x.PrimaryBar).ColumnPrefix("primary");
            mapping.Component(x => x.SecondaryBar).ColumnPrefix("secondary");
        }
    }
```

Do I really need to do a full override mapping or can what I have here be made to work somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting the way I have described in the question working.  It turned out to be a problem with our AutoMappingConfiguration which inherits from DefaultAutomappingConfiguration.  We weren't identifying Components properly.

Comment: This is not an answer. Answer should contains more details.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this a couple of years ago when I started with FNH. It's one of the few scenarios I've seen where FNH Automapping does not "just work".

The approach that was suggested to me at the time, which I've used successfully (with entities however, not components) is to create empty, intermediate entities, and reference them in the descendant class.

In your case, you could create two new, empty classes that inherit from BarComponent (say, PrimaryBarComponent and SecondaryBarComponent).

Then, in your Foo class, declare them as:

```
public PrimaryBarComponent PrimaryBar { get; set; }
public SecondaryBarComponent SecondaryBar { get; set; }
```

This is a kluge, in my opinion, but it works fine with entities and lists of entities, and does not require any overrides or conventions.

I've never used components with FNH, so I don't know if a similar approach will work, but it might be worth investigating.